# mod_rewrite - (skip www & define "new" subfolder/rootdir )

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What to skip the www in url - that works - here is the code I'm using

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

its working fine but : 
I would also like to jump to a subfolder ( without showing the subfolderName in url )
Is it possible to combine these 2 snippets ? cant get it to work.

other snippet :

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule   ^/$  /subfolder /  [R]
```

please help - guess it is a simple answer for an mod-rewrite expert :)

cheers

Comment: Every tried to put the rule right behind the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can combine them.
This will just forward ever request to the root of subfolder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^ subfolder [L]
```

Or you can do this if you want to shift the file requests over to the new directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteRule (.*) subfolder/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks , havent figured out the syntax jet :) But it works :)

If lets say you have a direct link - its it possible to remove to "subfolder" in the url ?